# Что такое FillDataSet?

Tags: c#

Учу Linq to DataSet, вот на MSDN код:

```cs
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

DataTable products = ds.Tables["Product"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from product in products.AsEnumerable()
    select product;

Console.WriteLine("Product Names:");
foreach (DataRow p in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Field<string>("Name"));
}
```

Что за метод на 3 строке?
Когда пишу его то подчеркивает.
Как его использовать?

Comment: это просто абстрактный метод для примера

Comment: Cоздайте свой метод `private void FillDataSet(DataSet ds) { ваш код }`.